# Does Content Security Policy (CSP) affect Google ranking? Pagespeed scores are worse without unsafe-inline

Tags: google-ranking, content-security-policy

I introduced Content Security Policy (CSP) in a website, nonetheless some of its commands and implications seem to negatively affect [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) ranking.

That happens in certain CSP configurations (the ones for example which do not introduce `'unsafe-inline'`), since by not allowing the introduction of inline style sheets nor inline scripts, a very important security measurement provided by CSP avoiding code injection, the page cannot in these CSP configurations be rendered so fast because inline data avoids page render blockig.

Therefore without `'unsafe-inline'` in CSP, it's much harder to get better ranking in Google Page Speed Insights. But CSP `'unsafe-inline'` improves security avoiding code injection, therefore I'm trying to find a balance between these two issues, CSP and Google Ranking from Page Insights.

- Does the existence of Content Security Policy (CSP) affect positively Google ranking?
- How important is ranking from Google Page Speed Insights in the overall Google Ranking?

Comment: Inlining JavaScript and CSS is often one of the best performance optimizations you can make.   I can't see implementing a security policy that doesn't allow that for myself.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller CSP evaluator from Google says "'unsafe-inline' allows the execution of unsafe in-page scripts and event handlers."

Comment: It does, but that is how the web has worked for years.   There are other ways to prevent XSS attacks such as proper sanitation of inputs.  I prefer using frameworks that apply escaping by default and you have to do something special to get data onto the page unescaped.